# Problem with minimized window to bottom gnome  panel

Tags: 12.04, gnome-panel, gnome-classic

It's difficult to explain, because English is not my native language, but here you have a few screenshots.

[Didn't work for me](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/05/install-ambiance-fixed-for-classic.html)

[image: <code>When mouse is on it</code>]

[image: when mouse isn't on it]

Why It becomes white and how to change it?
I'm using :

Ubuntu 12.04 64bit

Gnome Classic

Blue Ambience theme

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the theme? Here I use **Gnome Classic** with the *Ambiance* (default) theme and it's normal. See [screenshot](http://img854.imageshack.us/img854/7353/themeambiance.png).

Comment: yeah, I know, with Ambiance it works good, but i want Blue Ambiance.